# Actionbar and colorControlHilight

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using Actionbar in my app and I want to change its style. Specifically I want to change the color of the ripple when touching the different components of the actionbar.

**What I want is to style the action bar to have :**

- Texts with light colors.
- Light Highlight colors for actionbar icons (white circle ripple).
- Dark Highlight colors for the dropDown window of the `searchView`.

**What I achieved so far :**

- I've set the colors of the text to Light colors.
- I've changed the Highlight color of the actionbar icons to Light color.
- But this Light Highlight color is also propagated to the dropdown window, which I don't want...

Here's the style I created for my actionbar :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base.Theme4.ActionBar.Theme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_foreground_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Is there any way to put different Highlight colors for the icons and the dropdown window ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `sherlock action bar library` it will convenient to modify action bar as you want. you can download this library from given link-

http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

Comment: Thanks sud, but I have to keep the actionbar, I don't have the possibility to use the Sherlock actionbar...